# Options settlement in the event of an exchange halt

Tags: options, options-assignment

Are in-the-money options expiring on the current day guaranteed to be exercised in the event of a level 3 trading halt? Are there any circumstances, within or outside trading halts when options may not be exercised and be allowed to lapse even if they are in-the-money?